# Issues with layout_toLeftOf

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:text="TOP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@color/azul_pressed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:paddingLeft="100dp"
                android:text="|RIGHT--"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv1"
                android:text="--LEFT|"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
            android:text="BOTTOM"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

This line:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv1"
```

causes **tv2** to disapear from the screen and creates all that extra blue space.

Why?

Comment: Why not initialize your views top to bottom, left to right? Make the left one tv1, and have tv2 be toRightOf it.

Comment: @Michelle This is a testing layout which reproduces the problem of my real layout. In there, I cannot initialize my views top to bottom for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Tell me where tv1 and tv2 do you want to be placed exactly. It seems like you want tv1 and tv2 to be side by side and 100 dp from the left, right?

Answer (score 0):

In a relative layout you have to align you have to align your content to either the parent or to another widget.

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:text="|RIGHT--"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv2"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="--LEFT|"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

See how I aligned tv1 to the left of the parent and then tv2 to the right of tv1.

You can also do it the other way around.

Comment: I understand that your code and my code should both work, but they don't. In your version **tv2** keeps aligned to the very left of the screen. I want it right beside **tv1**

Comment: Just as trevor-e said you will need to use margin, so align tv1 to the left and add a margin of 100dp. then align th2 toLeftOf tv1

Comment: Hi, see my comment on trevor's answer, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing padding with margin?  Padding will move the text around in the TextView, and isn't actually part of the boundary.  Use margins instead if you want to push them from the side, or padding on the parent ViewGroup (same thing).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="--LEFT|"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="|RIGHT--"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv2"/>
```

This will place the views right next to each other.

If you want to then offset them by 100 pixels on the left, then add:

`android:margin_left="100dp"` to tv2.  Since tv1 is attached to the right of tv2, it will push both over by 100dp.  I'm not really sure what your intentions are, but I think a `LinearLayout` with gravity set on the children would be better since both textviews would occupy the same amount of space and be spread out evenly.

edit: note that this is similar to Carlos Paulino's answer.  I think you were confusing the padding offset of the text with the layout boundary.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter if I use paddings or margins, if I try to place tv2 `toLeftOf` tv1 it produces this weird output. Your solutions works. But why `toRightOf` works as expected and `toLeftOf` does not? I really would like to know why.

Comment: @Exception-al by weird output do you mean the picture in your original post?  What's happening in your original post is that the tv1 is being placed at the far left as a default location.  You are then setting tv2 to the left of it.  I think you are expecting that to then push both of them over, but what really is happening is tv2 just displays off the screen.  It doesn't display linearly since you are using relative positions.  The padding on the text of tv1 gives the illusion that it has been pushed over, but it's still hugging the left side of the parent.

Comment: got it, but what about the bottom space? it looks like tv1 or tv2 gained height

Comment: @Exception-al there is no other code modifying those views?  What is turning it blue?

Comment: this `android:background="@color/azul_pressed"` and there's nothing in the java file besides `setContentView`.

Comment: If you create a blank activity and just copy/past my layout you should get the same effect (even switching padding to margin) and if you use `toRightOf` the height goes back to normal.

Comment: @Exception-al I will try this out in a bit since I am curious.  Perhaps it is some undefined behavior due to the view being pushed off the screen that I don't know about.  I'll post back after I do my experiment.